# How can i make computed properties from HTML form satisfy a Typescript interface

Tags: typescript, forms

I've defined an interface according to my form fields:

```
interface IFormFields {
  fname: string;
  lname: string;
  phone: string;
  email: string;
}
```

I've target the form parent element by the input Event to access input values like this:

```
const form = document.querySelector("#contact-form") as HTMLFormElement;

const formData: IFormFields = {} as IFormFields;

form.addEventListener("input", (event: Event): void => {
  const target = event.target as HTMLInputElement;
  formData[target.name] = target.value;
});
```

The problem that i have is where i'm populating the `formData objet` using the computed properties with the following code `formData[target.name] = target.value;`

I'm getting the following error : `Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'IFormFields'.`

I know that i can solve the problem by changing my interface this way:

```
interface IFormFields{
   [key:string]:string;
}
```

And it works just fine.But the thing is that i've got a `validation function` that takes as `parametre` and that matches the first interface with `{fname:string;lname:string;...}`.

```
import { Validate } from "../lib/validator";

export interface FormData {
  fname: string;
  lname: string;
  email: string;
  phone: string;
}

interface IError {
  [key: string]: string;
}

interface IValid {
  errors: IError;
  isValid: boolean;
}

export function validateForm(formData: FormData) {
  const valid: IValid = {
    errors: {},
    isValid: true,
  };

  //   Fname validation
  if (!Validate.isMinMax(formData.fname, 3, 7)) {
    valid.errors.fname = "Please enter your first name";
  } else if (!Validate.isValidName(formData.fname)) {
    valid.errors.fname = "Please a valid firs tname";
  } else {
    valid.errors.fname = "";
  }

  //   Lname validation
  if (!Validate.isMinMax(formData.lname, 3, 7)) {
    valid.errors.lname = "Please enter your last name";
  } else if (!Validate.isValidName(formData.fname)) {
    valid.errors.lname = "Please a valid last name";
  } else {
    valid.errors.lname = "";
  }

  //   EMAIL
  if (!Validate.isRequired(formData.email)) {
    valid.errors.email = "Please enter your email";
  } else if (!Validate.isEmail(formData.email)) {
    valid.errors.email = "Please enter a valid email";
  } else {
    valid.errors.email = "";
  }

  //   PHONE
  if (!Validate.isRequired(formData.phone)) {
    valid.errors.phone = "Please enter your phone";
  } else if (!Validate.isValidPhone(formData.phone)) {
    valid.errors.phone = "Please enter a valid phone";
  } else {
    valid.errors.phone = "";
  }

  if (
    valid.errors.fname ||
    valid.errors.lname ||
    valid.errors.phone ||
    valid.errors.email
  ) {
    valid.isValid = false;
  } else {
    valid.isValid = true;
  }
  return valid;
}
```

And i'm making use of this function in the submit handler that look like this :

```
form.addEventListener("submit", (e: Event) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const isValid = validateForm(formData);

  if(isValid){
    //   good
  }else{
    //   Display errors in fields
  }
});
```

Here formData is the variable containing form fields

Sorry for mistakes,English isn't my first langage!

Answer (score 2):

I'd define the type based on a constant, readonly array of field names:

```typescript
// List the valid names
const FormFieldNames = ["fname", "lname", "phone", "email"] as const;

// The form type
type IFormFields = {
    [key in typeof FormFieldNames[number]]: string;
}
```

That looks different, but it ends up defining exactly the same interface that your first code block does:

```typescript
interface IFormFields {
    fname: string;
    lname: string;
    phone: string;
    email: string;
}
```

Defining it based on the array lets us create a type guard function for checking for a valid field name without repeating the field names:

```typescript
// A type guard function checking that the given string is a valid key for IFormFields
function validFormFieldName(name: string): name is keyof IFormFields {
    return FormFieldNames.includes(name as keyof IFormFields);
    // Sadly necessary, but harmless   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
}
```

Then your code using the form fields can use the type guard function to ensure that the name is valid:

```typescript
form.addEventListener("input", (event: Event): void => {
    const {name, value} = event.target as HTMLInputElement;
    if (!validFormFieldName(name)) {
        throw new Error(`Invalid form field name "${name}"`);
    }
    formData[name] = value;
});
```

This has the advantage that if you add a field to the form and forget to add it to the type, you'll get an error.

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-yHyHABVaAivZIqi0ej+jxCXBqEoMpkBBQcAEcSiqTxV04HdYBYYtRAAYksWALlgABaP9REradQH5RwAFlwAxABRRVSBBWxLF-dwABEdgwep52DQQcTafDWNbWxyD-QcN1wMinVgKA4FAqokLSVQoxUYtkBE+phNA2Bq3QahvQEAA+HFYniWj4CiJQ5EwLAoM4oQFJUwd0OYZolXwwiSMCAgZNgCjdBU5d4kgbJiwAQlMvA+3CAdJ1ISs8PbfF4iQZhqFDbdErI5h4uYYsxgIIKDXcVwsVTUh5AAEiMvg2lEEYlz0uIOnxP9GPQ4o+BMIRTKg9olyAA)

This is also useful later to validate an entire `IFormFields`. For instance, right now you have:

```typescript
const formData: IFormFields = {} as IFormFields;
```

...but that's incorrect, `{}` doesn't have the fields that `IFormFields` requires. Instead, you could use `Partial<IFormFields>`:

```typescript
const formData: Partial<IFormFields> = {};
```

Then you fill in the object until you're ready to submit it (or otherwise use it). But to submit it, you need `IFormFields`, not `Partial<IFormFields>`. So you have another type guard using that same array:

```typescript
// Type guard that checks the given Partial<IFormFields> is actually a
// complete IFormFields
function validIFormFields(fields: Partial<IFormFields>): fields is IFormFields {
    return FormFieldNames.every(name => name in fields);
}
```

Now you can use it:

```typescript
if (validIFormFields(formData)) {
    // Here, `formData` is now of type `IFormFields`:
    submit(formData);
    //     ^?
} else {
    // Deal with the fact some of the fields are missing...
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-yHyHI4Ag69cx8LaLBaEuZ7Y6yDpAACrC2bYAAPPOwYAHx1hcXbYFuGDIjQxCqIqLxNn2rbkJmJrSpgebQa2xbJlM9Sgcw4FYFBOFTDB1auMGdYkVMOKxPEnbdr2EzhAO0CDsgQwHpOpCCHBtZpMxrZLk+nRgAAqtAIp7EiVC0PQ-oeEIuDUJQZRAbAg4AI4lFUnirpwO6wCwxaiAAxJYsAIQAtNpoiVtOoD8o4ACy4AYgAooqpAgrYlhae4AAiOwYJRYGQJBbERHB0RtNYoAOMpqBUTRdF8QxwJwMgG6-Nk-g+NO0BVNmtB2Npg4brgQVOrAUAlZqzD2WkqhRioxbCUZ9StUZTFoNQ3oCHB7bxJF8BREochEeZbSCKAQ0goOLnMM0Sreb5AWBAQfWwCFuhGcu8SQNkxYAIREXg9FFqQYnIJWXmzficRIMw1ChtuANBcwf3dWMBCPQa7gyVwqbiaIAAki18G0ogjHJ+IdPi2mxS5xR8CYQgrcg7RyXhRoEc6JTlMQexkTFcX1Cli4cSuYCDhz8nIgA6ig6R7bA2aujGG43NQoCqqgoaIDsyzmNAJSqKo1A1V+4uVKYFjUOhmGoNpSI3aAxaQ8z9OsLjGAfaz8QOPyVTIHIIw43FMwwIQ-3ldqozMyMSL4grNN087LkYzbYD4leAD8T4bVgNXW3EDjRaV6zhkgCBJghDTa6gjb2uR2KwqgtN7i0HODk+QA)

Comment: Thank you very much.I've understood your solution.But according to the validation function, and submit handler i've added the full code. So you can see the whole context.That validation fonction take an objet containing all the fields.

Comment: @ChristianLisangola - That's fine, what problem do you see with it? The `IFormFields` type defined above is the same as the one at the top of your question (the one with fixed field names `fname`, `lname`, `phone`, and `email`. It's just how we define it that's different.

Comment: @ChristianLisangola - But why have `IFormFields` **and** `FormData`? They're the same interface. It would make more sense to just define it once.